# Relation name of my mother's sister's son's wife?

Tags: kinship-terms

My mother has a sister. That sister is then my aunt. My auntie's children are my first cousins. Is that correct? How then do I refer to my cousin's wife and their children. What is the relationship.

The sentence I wish to complete relates to the separation of my cousin and his wife. I wish to pass assurance to the wife and her daughter that they will forever be part of my family. The cousin not so much!

Comment: Your nth cousin's children are also your nth cousins but once removed. We would not normally refer to one's cousin's spouse by law as one's cousin.

Answer (score 4):

Your aunt's children are your first cousins.  Their children are your first cousins, once removed.  Your cousins' spouses are your cousins-in-law or your cousins by marriage.  The people I know generally dispense with such technical terms when they talk about their extended family; they just use *cousins* to describe the various types.

Your relationship to your relations is not governed by familial nomenclature.  Notice that

> You'll always remain part of my family

contains no terms of kinship.

Comment: Agree that your terms are correct, though I think your last sentence is key here for the OP's needs — @Phil, if you wish to show warmth to them, I don't think you get the same emotional weight from technically correct terms like "cousin-in-law"/"first cousin, once removed" here. I'd go with something along the lines of *"You'll always be family to me"; the more specific *"You'll always be a cousin-in-law to me"* not so much :)

Comment: +1 I agree with the terms technically, but I call my cousins' spouses *my cousins*, just as I call my stepbrothers *my brothers*.  Attitude counts more than law.

Comment: @anotherdave Good point.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: @bib *Attitude counts more than law.*  Except perhaps for tax law.  Good point for this situation. I've edited my answer.